# How to save image in specific sd card folder with using current time and data format in android?

Tags: android, android-file

I want to save a captured image in an SD-card specific folder with current time mills name of the image.

How can I do this?

Comment: [This](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html) example will do that. Have a look at that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this after getting the bitmap object

```
 private void save_Image_to_sdcard() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OutputStream file_outputstream = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        URL path = new URL(url);
        in = path.openStream();



        String path1 =    
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        System.out.println(path1+ "    " +user_file_name);
        // /mnt/sdcard
        File f = new File(path1 + "/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
        f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("file created " + f.toString());

        file_outputstream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {

            file_outputstream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        }

        file_outputstream.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("hey", "error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("hey", " ioexception");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Uri saveToFileAndUri() throws Exception{
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String fileName = "MY_APP_" + currentTime+".jpg";
    File extBaseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(extBaseDir.getAbsoluteFile()+"/MY_DIRECTORY");
    if(!file.exists()){
        if(!file.mkdirs()){
            throw new Exception("Could not create directories, "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, JPEG_QUALITY, out);     //control the jpeg quality
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    long size = new File(filePath).length();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(6);
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);

    // That filename is what will be handed to Gmail when a user shares a
    // photo. Gmail gets the name of the picture attachment from the
    // "DISPLAY_NAME" field.
    values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, currentTime);
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
    values.put(Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
    values.put(Images.Media.SIZE, size);

    return ThisActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save file as following way,

```
fileName + DateFormat.format( ConstantCodes.dd_MMM_yyyy_kk_mm_ss ,new java.util.Date()).toString() + ".jpg";
```